# Segmentation fault 11 when compiling in Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm getting a "segmentation fault 11"in Xcode when I try to compile. This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DataImportController {
    func startImport() {
        if let dataPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "stops", ofType: "csv") {
            do {
                let fileContents = try String(contentsOfFile: dataPath, encoding:.utf8)
                let contents = fileContents.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newLines)
            } catch  {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the message dump:

```
1.  While type-checking 'startImport' at /Users/Jaime/Developer/ETA/ETA/Model Controllers/DataImportController.swift:13:5
2.  While type-checking declaration 0x7fb185b34948 at /Users/Jaime/Developer/ETA/ETA/Model Controllers/DataImportController.swift:17:17
3.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/Jaime/Developer/ETA/ETA/Model Controllers/DataImportController.swift:17:32 - line:17:90] RangeText="fileContents.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newLines)"
```

Anything wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'm getting a "segmentation fault 11" in Xcode when I try to compile" Such a fault is always to be regarded as a bug. Report it at http://bugs.swift.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `CharacterSet.newLines` is meaningless. Did you mean `CharacterSet.newlines`...? Making that substitution (or writing simply `.newlines` alone) will permit your code to compile.

Comment: Not really an answer - should just be a comment ?

Comment: @PaulR No, it _is_ the answer. The question was whether something was wrong with the code. There is, and I told him what it was — and I suggested a fix. (The compiler _should_ have told him, but it segfaulted instead. Of course, consulting the documentation/headers would have told him too.) The fact that my answer is short is not the fault of the answer; it's the fault of the question.

Comment: OK- thanks for the clarification - I don't think the answer is clear though, as it doesn't link the error in the code to the compiler seg fault (or at least it wasn't obvious to me that these were related).

Comment: @PaulR My _comment_ to his question linked the error to the seg fault. That's a bug in the compiler (a bug which I cannot reproduce, by the way). A seg fault is _always_ a bug in the compiler. But _that was not the question_. He asked what was wrong with his code and I told him.

Comment: Sure - got it now - and I see you've made the answer clearer now - thanks.

Comment: @PaulR No worries — I took your critique seriously (though I think my original answer was a defensible answer).

Comment: No problem - I am currently jet-lagged and my brain and body seem to be in different time zones, so I was probably just being a bit slow to understand the answer. ;-)

Comment: The autocomplete didn't say anything either.